# Change session variable for all clicks except for one button in a page

Tags: asp.net, session, postback

I have got 10 button/Links in aspx page. I need to maintain a session variable on only ONE button click and for all other 9 click/action I need to change the value in session variable.

How can I get this in a best way, instead of writing in those 9 click actions.
Please suggest

Comment: You'll probably have to add a few examples of things you tried in order to receive any help. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

You can re-use the same event for multiple buttons, and check the 'sender' to see which button was clicked.

Markup:

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="GenericButtonClick" Text="Button" />
 <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="GenericButtonClick" Text="Button" />
```

CS:

```
protected void GenericButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            Button button = sender as Button;

            switch(button.ID)
            {
                case "Button1":

                    //Maintain Session Variable

                    break;

                default:

                    //Change Value in Session Variable

                    break;
            }
}
```

You then set all your buttons to use the same event handler

Answer (score 1):

I use mostly the command event handler instead of click, so in aspx side, you would have something like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnCommand="DoSomething" CommandName="SetSession" CommandArgument="true" />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnCommand="DoSomething" CommandName="SetSession" CommandArgument="false" />
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" OnCommand="DoSomething" CommandName="SetSession" CommandArgument="false" />
```

And in the back end cs file, there would be only one event handler like this:

```
protected void DoSomething(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandArgument.ToString() == "true")
    {
        // set session    
    }

}
```

The benefit of using CommandEventHandler is that even later on you change the button to ImageButton or LinkButton, you don't need to change the event signature, it works for all.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `property` in which you can set the `session value` and you can also get value from this property. I have made it `private` because it is used only in that page where you need.

```
private static string SetGetSession
{
    set { HttpContext.Current.Session["Mairaj"] = value; }
    get { return HttpContext.Current.Session["Mairaj"].ToString(); }
}
```

Here is how you can use it

```
protected void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetGetSession = "Mairaj";
}
protected void btnTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetGetSession = "Ahmad";
}
protected void btnTh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetGetSession = "Minhas";
}
```

If you want it to be used in other pages as well you can make a `class` and make this property `public` you will be able to access it everywhere.